# How to detect code blocks for a language like Python

Tags: python, split

I have an issue I can't wrap my head around. I want to be able to detect (i.e. get the start and end line) coded blocks defined like they are in Python.

For instance, the following code :

```
def main():
    foo = "bar"
    if foo != "baz":
        foo = "tab"
    else:
        foo = "wow"
    for character in foo:
        print(character)
    return 1
```

Would yield the following result `[(0, 8), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]`. Furthermore, I need this to be optimized for speed, because indeed, I need block detection to be executed every time the content of the code changes. I think a tree-like structure to organize the blocks seems ideal (with the `if`, `else` and `for` blocks in the example being children of the `def` block).

I have tried this code :

```
def detect_block(text):
    import re
    tabs = re.compile(r'( {4})')
    start_re = re.compile(r' *(elif|else|except|finally|for|if|try|while|with|label|screen|transform|init|layeredimage|menu|style|# *region|def)\b')
    end_re = re.compile(r' *(\n|break|continue|return|yield|yield from|pass|# *endregion)\b')
    start_indices = []
    end_indices = []
    rv = []
    for line_nb, line in enumerate(text.split("\n")):
        indent = len(tabs.findall(line))
        if start_re.match(line):
            start_indices.append((line_nb, indent))
        elif end_re.match(line):
            end_indices.append((line_nb, indent))
    for i, (idx, idx_indent) in enumerate(start_indices):
        for jdx, jdx_indent in end_indices:
            if jdx_indent == idx_indent and jdx > idx:
                rv.append((idx, jdx))
                break
    return rv
```

but I don't get the expected result. I've been stuck on this problem for several days now.

Comment: a hint, work off of indentation and `:`, not keywords.This with regex will probably be a lot more pain inducing then it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks. I already thought about indentation (as you can see in my try), but I didn't think about the `:` punctuation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html and look for INDENT/DEDENT tokens.

Comment: Have check: from dis import dis;print(dis(main))?

Comment: dis isn't helpful here because I want to parse text. Not get traceback info as the code is not run